# Flutter Services

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

¿Como implementar servicios en fluter?

Tengo la inquietud de hacer una app en flutter en donde cada 10 minutos guarde la ubicacion del dispositivo y luego guardarlo en la base de datos sqlite?

Lo que me interesa es arrancar el servicio. He uscado y no encuentro un ejemplo claro!!!

Ayuda!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres servicios debes ir al nativo tanto tanto en iOS(swift) como en Android(Java/Kotlin) y el resto de la aplicación si la puedes llevar a cabo con Flutter donde te comunicas a traves de MethodChannels
https://flutter-es.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Gracias!!! lo voy a implementar